# How do I "lop the top off" off a repository in git?

Tags: git

I have a git repository that has 20 branches, labeled Step1 through Step20, each is a branch that branches off the previous branch.

That is, Step1 merges into Step2, which merges into Step3, etc.

I want to "lop off" everything after the Step12 branch.  In other words, I want a repository with only Step1 through Step12, and nothing above that.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to delete branches `Step13` through `Step20`.

There's no single "lop the top off" operation in Git. As long as one branch points at a commit after a specific point (ie, after whatever `Step12` points to), you cannot remove that commit or any prior commits, meaning if you removed `Step13` through `Step19`, every intermediate commit would still exist in the history of `Step20`.

By deleting all the branches that point to commits you're no longer interested in keeping, you allow those commits to be garbage collected and eventually removed from the repo.